# Axios API Twitter request not returning back user tweets

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, twitter, axios

I am trying to call Twitters API and get a my tweets back so I can post them on a website I am creating.

When I run the following code I get an error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%SamSchaeferSays. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3333' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400." And "bundle.js:30041 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error.

I am new to API calls not using PHP - not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
const tweet = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%SamSchaeferSays';
function getUserTweet() {
    return axios.get(`${tweet}`).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.status)
    });
}
```

sample OAuth string

```
const DST = `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${consumerKey}",
oauth_nonce="${}", 
oauth_signature="${}", 
oauth_signature_method="${}", 
oauth_timestamp="${}", 
oauth_token="${}", 
oauth_version="1.0"
 `;
```

Comment: `400` means bad request. entry point is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `400 Bad Request` error means that the server doesn't understand your request. In your case there's a typo that prevents the request from going through (extra `%`). Try this:

```
const tweet = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=SamSchaeferSays';
function getUserTweet() {
    return axios.get(`${tweet}`, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'YOUR_OAUTH_HEADER' } }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.status)
    });
}
```

This will fix the `400 Bad Request` error, but you won't get any data back yet. The Twitter API requires you to authorize your request. Find out more in [their documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests).

> To allow applications to provide this information, Twitter’s API relies on the OAuth 1.0a protocol. At a very simplified level, Twitter’s implementation requires that requests needing authorization contain an additional HTTP Authorization header with enough information to answer the questions listed above. A version of the HTTP request shown above, modified to include this header, looks like this (normally the Authorization header would need to be on one line, but has been wrapped for legibility here):

Comment: I thought the OAuth was for streaming requests?  I set one up but the Authorization header confuses me - like where I am suppose to send that out from.

Comment: In my axions.get do I send my current information + an array called Authorization containing all of the OAuth stuff?

Comment: You will need to set this header at every request, Twitter is very strict about this. I updated my question with a `Authorization` header.

Comment: at the Authorization: 'YOUR_OAUTH_HEADER' - this contains oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, oauth_token and oauth_version ?  Do I provide that as an array?

Comment: As a string it seems. Check the documentation I linked to, it should explain it.

Comment: Nice I see it, thank you.  I added the string I will use above ( let me know if you think its incorrect), and now I just need to figure out where to find the values.  Seems like they want you to produce a lot of the values.

Comment: You'll need to create these values yourself, except for the consumer key. The documentation should help you with that. If you run into problems you can ask another question on here, but please try it yourself first as this is not a tutorial site.